# Need Advice - Dynamically setting parameters/properties with javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ecmascript-6

is there a way to dynamically set a parameter, or property for a function in javascript? some examples:

```
const funcOne = (param1, param2) => console.param1(param2);

funcOne(log, `hello there`);
```

obviously the above doesnt work, just bring an example, same as below:

```
const mongoFunc = param, filter => Collection.param(filter, (err, foundArticle) => {
// code block
});
```

this will work:

```
const funcOne = (param1, param2) => console.log(param1, param2);
funcOne(`hello`, `there`);
```

so I was wondering if theres a dynamic way to set the log in console.log same as when it comes to mongo to dynamically set Collection.find or collection.findOneAndUpdate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Is "currying" what are you looking for, maybe? https://javascript.info/currying-partials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do it.
First of all, in an  object, you can access/create a dynamic key using `[]` as in:

```
object[dynamicKey] = 'someVal';
```

where the dynamicKey string is a key you want to access in an object.
Example

```
const sampleObject = {
   name: 'stack',
   flow: true,
};

const setDynamicKey = (o, k, v) => (o[k] = v);

setDynamicKey(sampleObject, 'hello', 'world!');
console.log(sampleObject); // { name: 'stack', flow: true, hello: 'world!' }
```

Now for your case, you can do something like

```
const funcOne = (param1, param2) => console[param1](param2);

funcOne('log', 'hello there');
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll first of all have to pass **log as a string** because otherwise it will throw an error saying log is undefined.

You can try this:

```
const funcOne = (param1, param2) => console[param1](param2);
funcOne('log', `hello there`);
```

If you want to dynamically access an object's property in javascript you have to use square bracket notation.

Hope this helps!